# dask - speed up column filtering

Tags: python-3.x, vectorization, dask

I have a 18 GB `.parquet` file with a ~300M rows of accounting data (which I cannot share) and split in to 53 row groups.  My task is to 'clean' the data by retaining in each cell, only specific words from a dictionary.  The reading of the file is trouble free.  The processing of the file ends in a segmentation fault on a 20-core, 128GB RAM Ubuntu 22.04 desktop.

Using Python and the Dask library, I convert the data in to a Dask data frame with the following columns:

```
['rowid', 'txid', 'debit', 'credit', 'effective_date', 'entered_date', 'user_id', 'transaction', 'memo', 'type', 'account', 'total_amt']
```

The columns to be cleaned in this file are `memo`, `type`, and `account`.  My approach is to take each of those columns and apply a `filter_field` and a `hash_field` method to them:

```
        if isinstance(data, dd.DataFrame):
            # clean memo columns
            # data = data.repartition(npartitions=20) <incl. this line in experiments with partition size>
            result = [data[col].apply(lambda x: self.filter_field(text=x, word_dict=word_dict), meta=data[col]) for col in memo_columns]
            for i, col in enumerate(memo_columns):  # this loop seems to be req'd to assign values
                data[col] = result[i]
            
            # second: hash the name/id fields
            id_cols = name_columns + id_columns + account_columns
            result = [data[col].apply(lambda x: self.hash_field(text=x), meta=data[col]) for col in id_cols]
            for i, col in enumerate(id_cols):
                data[col] = result[i]
                
            del result
            gc.collect()
```

The filter_field takes each cell, removes symbols, then checks to see if remaining words are in a dictionary, and if they are not the words are dropped.

The hash_field is just `shake_256(text.encode(encoding='utf8')).hexdigest(20)`.

I know the filtering is sound b/c everything runs fine on near identical files of up to 128M rows.  Two things happen when I run this larger file:

1. at some point I get a segmentation fault.  Sometimes it happens early in the processing, sometimes later.
2. rarely are more than 3 cores processing at more 30-50% and when there are more the additional cores are at ~1-2% (observed via htop)

What I would like to know:

1. is there a better approach than the looping/vectorizing I used; or
2. how can I get more cores working on the process.

Notes:

1. I tried various approaches with partition size changes, both by varying number and size.  There was no visible improvement in processing and the large file still threw a seg fault.
2. what I expect my approach to be doing is taking each column presented, dividing it in to ~20 pieces, then processing those pieces in parallel (one piece per processor).

Comment: Please read up on `map_partitions`, the all-purpose tool for this kind of situation

Comment: I played with them incl. number and size (100MB as in Dask example and up to 10GB b/c why not?).  There was no visible improvement over the code presented here ie. few cores seem to be getting used.

Comment: Do you read the input Data directly using Dask? Are you using a LocalCluster, or just the default threaded Scheduler?

Comment: @GuillaumeEB reading directly with .read_parquet, just running default scheduler.

Comment: Then I would recommand trying this with a LocalCluster, multi processing will probably give a better speedup on your use case, and with the Dashboard you should be able to better analyse any memory problem.